# Which Game of Thrones books correspond to each TV series season?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, adaptation-comparison

Which of the Game of Thrones books have been televised during the first season (April to June 2011)? I want to start reading the novels from when the TV series stopped in 2011.

Answer (score 12):

Just the first one, *A Game of Thrones*. You need to start with the second book, *A Clash of Kings*, but bear in mind that the TV adaptation is necessarily abridged, and you'll probably find some characters and plot elements that you're not familiar with.

Comment: Also, there is one important event (that I can think of) that will be at the start of the second season (it happens at the end of the first book). I think you should start reading a couple chapters before the end of the first book (as it seems you aren't interested in reading the whole book).

Answer (score 12):

I would advise that you start reading from the beginning.  The TV series is not an exact reproduction of the book.  Many events and characters were omitted, and some were changed, as one would expect in an adaptation.  The Song of Ice and Fire is one continuous story.  If you skip the first book, you will miss big chunks of it.

Comment: Agreed, read the first book if you want to read the series. If any fantasy-series written in the last twenty-years deserves to be read, its this one.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the TV seriels this June and then I went for the books for more detail about the whole story. 
According to my reading experiences, I recommand you to read the whole books from the very first one. Because in the TV , HBO just ommited many events and characters(just as mentioned above). 
And what really matters is that, you almost cannot know what the character is thinking about in the TV, but when you are reading the book, you will get to know more. The book helped me to know many characters were not what I thought from the TV.